# Linq to SQL query not returning expected results

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lambda

Can anyone explain to me why these two are different functionally?

The first returns null on my sample data, and the second returns the expected result. I put the `+ @""` part in to avoid calling replace on a null string.

*Code always returns null on my sample data:*

```
to_follows_contact = db.CONTACTs.Where(n =>
    n.ACCOUNTID == account.ACCOUNTID
    && (
        (n.FIRSTNAME + n.MIDDLENAME + n.LASTNAME + @"").Replace(@" ", @"") 
                                                            == @"TOFOLLOW"
        ||
        (n.FIRSTNAME + n.MIDDLENAME + n.LASTNAME + @"").Replace(@" ", @"") 
                                                            == @"FOLLOWTO"
    )
).FirstOrDefault();
```

*Code returns correct contact on my sample data:*

```
foreach (CONTACT n in db.CONTACTs.Where(n => n.ACCOUNTID == account.ACCOUNTID))
{
    string ContactName = (n.FIRSTNAME + n.MIDDLENAME + n.LASTNAME + @"")
                         .Replace(@" ", @"");
    if (ContactName == @"TOFOLLOW" || ContactName == @"FOLLOWTO")
        to_follows_contact = n;
}
```

Comment: So far, I'm as puzzled with your problem as you are... I just wanted to point out that the `@` signs for C# verbatim strings are not necessary in this case.

Comment: Try taking a look at the generated SQL, might be an issue there.

Comment: @Thorarin: I just got into the habit of always using @ in front of strings unless I explicitly wanted escape characters. That way, I don't have to worry about windows paths stored as strings (which I do a lot).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's happening, is that the first code sample actually solves the problem entirely in T-SQL. Unfortunately, the translation from C# to SQL isn't entirely transparent.

SQL handles null values differently* from .NET. `SELECT 'Foo' + NULL + 'Bar'` will return `NULL`. You will need to use COALESCE or something like it. In LINQ to SQL, that translates to:

```
(n.FIRSTNAME ?? "" + n.MIDDLENAME ?? "" + n.LASTNAME ?? "").Replace(" ", "")
```

If you use that, it should work fine.

If you're interested, you can use `db.GetCommand(IQueryable<T>)` to get the generated SQL statement. It's also available when you hover over the IQueryable variable in a piece of source code while debugging.

*: this acually depends on some database options that you can set, but this is the default behavior.

Comment: Nice. I haven't come across the ?? operator in C# before.

Comment: @Jonathan: it's aptly named the null-coalescing operator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, the generated SQL will concatenate the various strings, however, if one of them is null, then you'll always get NULL returned from the concatenation, which will fail to pass your equality test.

In the code, the strings will always be empty, which will then work.